# How to ensure my dependencies use Safe Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to declare in the Cargo.toml that my project depend only on 3rd-party crates that guaranteed to be using Safe Rust transitively?

I am new to Rust and Rust is new to me. I haven't had a chance to try anything out yet.

Answer (score 7):

## Analyzing Dependencies

First, check the crates.io documentation whenever the author(s) mention the usage of unsafe code. You can double-check it by searching for the `unsafe` keyword in the source code.

However, inspecting the crate's and its dependencies' source code is a tedious job. The tool called [cargo-geiger](https://github.com/rust-secure-code/cargo-geiger) provide statistics about unsafe usage in the crate and all its dependencies. After installing it, navigate to your `Cargo.toml` file and analyze it:

```
cargo geiger
```

It will download and scans all dependencies, then assigns one of the three symbols to a crate:

```
Symbols: 
      = No `unsafe` usage found, declares #![forbid(unsafe_code)]
    ❓  = No `unsafe` usage found, missing #![forbid(unsafe_code)]
    ☢️   = `unsafe` usage found
```

Note that it provides only the usage of `unsafe` keyword. But for more thorough analysis, review the code with [cargo-crev](https://github.com/crev-dev/cargo-crev) to verify the trustworthiness and the security vulnerabilities of package dependencies. Additionally, if you found an unsafe code, you can report to the [safety-dance](https://github.com/rust-secure-code/safety-dance) repository.

## Analyzing Project

Once you checked your dependencies, it is time to assess your project as well. For start, catch common mistakes using the `clippy` linter tool:

```
cargo clippy
```

Moreover, add the `#![forbid(unsafe_code)]` attribute to your files to communicate that unsafe code blocks are forbidden. I don't know if you can declare that your package (is guaranteed) to use safe Rust. But you can show a badge in the `README.md` file after eliminating all `unsafe` code:

```
[![unsafe forbidden](https://img.shields.io/badge/unsafe-forbidden-success.svg)](https://github.com/rust-secure-code/safety-dance/)
```

It will help others to discover that your crate is safe.

Note that there is no 100% memory safety in Rust because the standard libraries use (with great caution) `unsafe` blocks. Sometimes it is unavoidable. In any case, you should always try to implement **safe** code, even if you lose a little performance gain.

*Less bug, less maintenance pain, more tRust.*

Further readings:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines
- https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/

Comment: `#![forbid(unsafe_code)]` isn't a macro, it's just a built-in attribute. But the rest of this post is very thorough!

Comment: Thank you for the review, the comment was incorporated.